# What's wrong with this simple jquery plugin example?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

What have I done wrong? It worked before I separated the methods as suggested in the jquery docs.
Calling: `$(this).Slick('show');`

```
(function ($) {

var methods = {

    // object literals for methods
    init: function (options) {

        // initialize settings
        var settings = $.extend({
            'location': 'center',
            'speed': 'normal'
        }, options);
    },
    show: function () {

        return this.each(function () {

            // plugin code here
            alert('success!');
        });
    },
    hide: function () {

        // hide
    }
};

$.fn.Slick = function (method) {
    // method calling logic -- jquery recommended / standard
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments 1));
    } else if (typeof(method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.Slick');
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: "It worked before I separated the methods" --- rollback your code to the state when it worked. And repeat the same once again, by small steps, line by line. After each tiny iteration check if everything works as expected. When you get it broken - you definitely know what exact small portion of changes caused that (it is called **debugging**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two syntax errors.

Missing comma:

```
return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments 1));
```

Missing closing parenthesis:

```
} else if (typeof(method === 'object' || !method) {
```

Comment: That should do it.  You really should install Firebug or use one of the other browser's developer tools.  Firebug's console immediately threw an error pointing out the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Somthing else you may find useful.  I had a hard time writing jQuery plugins for a long time till i finally created this simple formula that has always worked for me since i started using it.

```
(function($) {
    if (!$.myExample) {
        $.extend({
            myExample: function(elm, command, args) {
                return elm.each(function(index){
                    // do work to each element as its passed through
                });
            }
        });
        $.fn.extend({
            myExample: function(command) {
                return $.myExample($(this), command, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

This gives you everything you need to begin setting up a jQuery plugin that will work in typical jQuery fashion through both `$.myExample($("someEle"))` and `$("someEle").myExample()`